# ...hoped that you would/could have been

Tags: word-choice, modal-verbs

X: "It's a big thing, so I was there with her."

Y: "How did it go?"

X: "Fine, though I think she had hoped that you would/could have been there too."

- Is the third piece of dialogue natural in the context?
- What is the difference between 'would' and 'could' here?
- Which one of them would you use? (Info: Y didn't go because he was tired.)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, seems natural to me.

They both mean that she wanted Y to be there, but he wasn't.  "could" implies that X thinks that Y didn't come because he was unable to come.  "would" might imply that X thinks Y didn't care enough to come.

If X is trying to make Y feel bad, he might use "would".  Otherwise he might use "could".  But it's not that big of a difference.